# Sqlite3 FTS: Limiting length of items between two words in match request?

Tags: regex, sqlite, full-text-search, match

I have a table called "topic_overview" that has an "topic_id" field and an "overview" field. The overview contains text descriptions of a topic(that related the id of the topic).

I am trying to figure out how to list the ids of the topics so that they contain the terms “word_1” and “word_2” in the overview field with not more than 5 intervening terms in between.

This is what I've done so far (i'm have a hard time figuring out what the syntax is for limiting the amount of items between word_1 and word_2 to 5):

```
    SELECT id FROM topic_overview
    WHERE overview match 'word_1 AND word_2';
```

Comment: Doesn't `word_1 NEAR/5 word_2` work for you?

Comment: Thanks @UlugbekUmirov that works fine. I had missed that when i scanned the documentation.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Please write that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [NEAR query](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#near)

```
SELECT id FROM topic_overview
WHERE overview match 'word_1 NEAR/5 word_2';
```